# How to import a single property named with dot notation from package.json?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

SonarQube detects the following code as a mistake ("Wildcard imports should not be used") :

```
import * as packageJson from '../../../package.json';
```

We use only a few of properties contained in package.json

For instance, no problem for the version, I can use that :

```
import { version } from '../../../package.json';
```

In our package.json , I want to use a property named with dot notation :

```
...
"project.id": "123456",
...
```

But the following import gives me a compilation error  :

```
import {['project.id'] as projectId } from '../../../package.json';
```

```
error TS1141: String literal expected.
```

How to get correctly this single project.id property from package.json ?
I don't want to rename it.

Comment: This is because it's `import { ['project.id']: projectId } from '../../../package.json';`. Replace `as` with `:`

Comment: same error by replacing as with :

Comment: `import packageJson from '../../../package.json';` should work fine, therefore negating the wildcard. [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vmyway?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: by negating the wildcard I have another error : TS1259: Module '"C:/myworkspace/git/project/package"' can only be default-imported using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag  package.json(1, 1): This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag.

Answer (score 0):

One solution you can change project in your package.json as below

```
"project":  {
   "id": "123456"
 }
```

and import like

```
import { project } from '../../project.json';
```

Comment: because this project.id property is used by library spread into several projects we do not want to change it. It would be the last solution ...